# 2+ modems on the same home network

Tags: networking, router

I'm about to move into a house with pretty weak broadband (UK ADSL, maybe 4mbps, but unlimited cap)

The area is pretty well served by mobile 4G, but the prices/packages are still a bit small to be a safe replacement (for now)

I'm looking for some thoughts/tips on the idea of being able to have a wired and wireless internet connection on the same network, and using a proxy/server/middleman (I have spare PCs) to prioritise and push traffic through either connection depending on priorities I assign (and then everything to the wired connection once the cap is hit)

I appreciate I can't have the same stream of data shared between the two without going through a vpn etc, so I'd look to (for example) have iplayer/netflix pushed to the mobile modem, while steam/google photo backup are on the fixed line.

Comment: If you're worried about the caps wouldn't the other way around be more logical? as for your question you could look into QoS assignments. It would also depend on whenever you're looking to distinguish by type of service or "service provider" (e.g. Amazon Prime and Netflix would be a different thing).

Comment: fair point re priority, I'm just looking at the general solution for now, can tweak the rules depending on what fits :)

Comment: Naively I'd just thought that anything going to *.netflix.com would go one route, and *.steam.com another

Comment: If you have a spare PC, setup `pFsense` on it, it greatly working with multiple WANs, [here](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN) is how to set it up. You can create multiple rules and priorities on it.